# Bulk removing Features On Demand payloads from Windows 8?

Tags: windows, disk-space-utilization, dism

Short of running `dism /online /disable-feature /remove /featurename:featurename` on every feature I'd like to prune, is there a way of removing the payload on disk for all disabled features?

Comment: I was going to suggest a bit of PowerShell, but `Get-WindowsFeature` doesn't seem to work on Windows 8...

Comment: Get-WindowsFeature and Install/Remove-WindowsFeature only work against Server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Powershell 3.0 in Windows 8 provides a new cmdlet named [Get-WindowsOptionalFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852173.aspx) which can be used to query features and their current state. With a little filtering you can pass this along the chain and execute dism for each feature.

```
Get-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online | where { $_.State -match "Disabled" } | `
    foreach { `
        $_ = $_.FeatureName; `
        DISM /Online /Disable-Feature /FeatureName:$_ /Remove `
    }
```

Additional Links

- [Enable or Disable Windows Features Using DISM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824822.aspx)
- [Use PowerShell to Find Disabled Features in Windows 8](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/10/powertip-use-powershell-to-find-disabled-features-in-windows-8.aspx)
- [Manage Windows Features from Command Line with DISM](http://tweaks.com/windows/40255/manage-windows-features-from-command-line-with-dism/)

Comment: I find that matching `Disabled$` is better because then it only processes features that aren't already in the "Disabled with Payload Removed" state.

Comment: PowerShell Remove-WindowsFeature -Remove can also do this against servers or server offline images.